# I'm trying to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu but installer is unable to find drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I downloaded the ISO for Linux Ubuntu onto my flash drive and used [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/191054/how-to-create-bootable-usb-drives-and-sd-cards-for-every-operating-system/)  with universal USB installer to make Linux bootable from the flash drive.

I used windows disk management to allocate plenty of space for a my Linux environment next to my windows one.

I rebooted and hit F12 to get into the one time boot menu and found the USB listed there so I started Linux and clicked the install Linux icon.

It gave me the language options and then the option to connect to the internet and then I got a screen that said `Unable to install Linux on this machine. It requires 7 gigs and the machine is only 4.` (paraphrasing)

I opened `gparted` in the terminal to see if I could find the host machine's SSD but the only thing that came up was the USB drive. How can I get around this and install Ubuntu alongside windows? Normally that's the screen that would show up after the option to connect to WiFi... but I didn't get that. It's like it can't see the my machine.

Comment: my boot mode is set to UEFI and secure boot is ON, I tried turning it off but that didnt help

Comment: Will be easier to answer if you mention the version of Windows you are using and the version of Ubuntu you want to install. Check if secure boot is enabled or not. The space you allocated for Ubuntu, is it showing up as **Unallocated** space?

Comment: So I found some sort of an answer on a forum that said if I format the drive, reinstall windows 10 but in AHCI mode instead of RAID, then I will be able to install ubuntu alongside it. I did that and it worked great but the only problem is that Ubuntu doesn't show up in the boot menu next to the Windows boot manager like it should. I even looked into GParted as I was installing Ubuntu and it showed that the drive now had an ext4 partition and a swap partition. I've done this once before successfully on a Dell Inspiron so I know the process. This new computer is a Dell XPS 13.

Comment: any ideas why ubuntu doesn't show up in the boot list on startup?

Answer (score 0):

What are the specs of your system:  Motherboard, BIOS version, CPU, RAM, etc.

Just poking this in here, but here are the recommended minimum requirements for the desktop version of Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements.

Just going through the basic's first.  Believe me, when I do tech support for family when their systems won't boot, first thing is always "is the system plugged in."  You do not want to know how often the answer is no.

If you indeed only have partitioned 4GB, that might just be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Some distros need an installer to make the iso bootable on usb (eg `usb installer`) , others require that you do an image copy (eg with `disk imager`)
to make the iso into a bootable USB.  I can't say which method is more likely to work for an unspecified version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out finally what the issues were. I had to reinstall windows in AHCI mode instead of RAID (this is a Dell XPS 13 with an SSD drive) I then shrunk about 100GIGs to make room for linux ubuntu alongside windows and installed ubuntu from a flash drive. I had to MAKE SURE I connected to wifi when I installed ubuntu (I had previously skipped that step) because otherwise it wouldn't add ubuntu to the grub menu on startup for some reason. So there's my solution in case some one finds it helpful during a dualboot